# A peristaltic pump with pH sensor and web based output project

Tags: arduino-uno, web-server, uart, esp8266webserver, arduino-iot-cloud

Good day to you all, I am asking here to confirm that my project is feasible. I have low knowledge of Arduino and other components. Please help me in achieving this project.

I already have the peristaltic pump and pH sensor working with Arduino uno. Now I want the output of the pH sensor to be displayed in a webpage or web app, In the webpage I will also make a formula on how much volume is released from the peristaltic pump.

So there are two things on my webpage output: the acidity of the liquid and the volume released. I want a wireless setup, so I guess I would use ESP32 (notsure)? Now I kind of getting hard on how to put it on a webpage and the important part is, how to pass the data from the arduino to the ESP32?. Any ideas? or things that I would do?

OR

I  would use the ESP32 alone since I have not so many components and I think the ESP32 can cater for the pHsensor (analog signal) and pwm (motor Peristaltic pump). Correct me if I'm wrong. By this, I won't be having problems about the communication to the arduino and esp32 (UART).

Additional Info:
Current Set up-
Arduino - controls the pump and pHsensor
ESP32 - Webpage or webserver

Is there any way that I could do this with ESP32 alone? so that I won't be having problems with UART.

I want to thank you in advance for giving me insights.

Update:

by this I decided to use ESP32 alone for the whole project. I just need to rewire all. I'm hoping the ESP32 has PWM pins to control the pwm peristaltic pump and pHsensor(analog signal) pins. Please confirm if you know that ESP32 has these pins(for pwm and analog). By the way I'm using the ESP32S where the TXD0 is in pin 35 which is the GPIO1 and the RXD0 is in pin 34 which is the GPIO3. –
Johannes Remotigue
2 days ago   Delete

Comment: Not knowing what you have you first need to determine if it will be wired or wireless. Then narrow it down, wireless could be wifi, bluetooth, etc. After that you then need to determine if you want it on one arduino such as an ESP32 or use shields/modules..

Comment: start by learning how to display "Hello World" in a web page ... forget about the pump and the pH sensor for now

Comment: @Gil Thank you, my question is now updated.

Comment: @jsotola Thank you, I already know the html and css in making a web page. What else do I need to learn? like the backend, on how to get the data?

Comment: Is this web server going to be on the Arduino or ESP32?

Comment: @NickGammon you mean if it is going to be on the Arduino, I should have an ethernet shield right? 

I'm actually adjusting my set up to which is more doable for me.

Comment: I was just asking. Where do you intend the web server to be? You could conceivably send data to a PC, and have the web server there. To do it on the Arduino, yes you would need an Ethernet shield. It has to accept incoming TCP/IP connections somehow.

Comment: Thank you @NickGammon, by this I decided to use ESP32 alone for the whole project. I just need to rewire all. I'm hoping the ESP32 has PWM pins to control the pwm peristaltic pump and pHsensor(analog signal) pins. Please confirm if you know that ESP32 has these pins(for pwm and analog). By the way I'm using the ESP32S where the TXD0 is in pin 35 which is the GPIO1 and the RXD0 is in pin 34 which is the GPIO3.

Comment: @JohannesRemotigue `how to get the data?` ... that's what I'm talking about ... learn how to send "Hello World" from arduino to webbrowser

Comment: This isn't a forum. Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking, don't ask additional things in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will need to add a solid state switch or similar to power the motor. The ESP32 has the radio needed to connect to your wifi so that part is already there. The ESP can be configured as a client or server so take your pick. There is a lot published on the web about doing this with code even posted. The device also has a lot of computing power so it could become a stand alone device which reports the results to the web server or works in conjunction with it.

All you will need to add is mainly code.  This should get you started. Just be cautious as the Arduino is generally 5V and the ESP is 3.3 volt so some voltage translation may be needed and if using 5V modules and/or MOSFETS. If MOSFETs are involved be very careful of the Vgs ratings to be sure it is on with 3V.